# TYPO3: variables not working

Tags: variables, typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

Using variables in T3 aren't working.
I actually just copied the snippets from a working site.

**TS:**

```
page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.10.variables {
    content < styles.content.get
    content.select.where = colPos=0

    info < styles.content.get
    info.select.where = colPos=1
}
```

**Inside the HTML template:**

```
<f:format.html parseFuncTSPath="">{info}</f:format.html>
<f:format.html parseFuncTSPath="">{content}</f:format.html>
```

The template is being included, added a random `<hr/>` to make sure changes are displayed in the FE.
Dummy content is inserted in the correct columns in the BE (colPos 0 & 1).
Also tried it without the `<f:format.html>` and with a `<f:format.raw>`.
*EDIT:* Well, even though it's obvious, I also made sure I'm on the correct page (uid=2).

Can anyone help? Thanks.
I'm running T3 7.6.9

Answer (score 1):

Well, I knew it was somewhere obvious:

I forgot to include the `fluid_styled_content` includes.